# Create matrices of a certain format

Tags: python, performance, matrix, numpy

I need to create matrices that follow a specific format: the matrix is a square NxN matrix and the off-diagonals all have the same value (`param`) and the diagonals have values such that the rows sum to zero (in other words, they are equal to `0 - param * (N-1)`. The output is a numpy array

Here is my code. Is there any way I can make this more readable/elegant? Speed is also important.

```
import numpy as np

def makeMatrix(param, N):
    ar = []
    for i in range(N):
        ar.append([ param for st in range(N) ])
        ar[i][i] = 0-(param*(N-1))

    return np.array(ar, dtype=np.double)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the main features of NumPy is that you can work with matrices without explicit looping.  To get the diagonal, use `np.identity()`.  To set everything else, use [broadcasting](//stackoverflow.com/a/5891447/1157100).

```
def make_matrix(value, dim):
    return value - value * dim * np.identity(dim, dtype=np.double)
```

`param` and `N` don't mean anything to me.  I suggest `value` and `dim`.  The function name should preferably be `make_matrix`, [according to PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions).

Answer (score 3):

You're calculating the diagonal value every time even though it's always the same. Just calculate it once before the loop.

```
diagonal = -param * (N - 1)
```

It's a little bit faster to make a list comprehension than loop and append to a list, even if you still need to loop over the list afterwards to set the values

```
ar = [[param for _ in range(N)]
      for i in range(N)]
for i in range(N):
    ar[i][i] = diagonal
```

You *can* fold in the diagonal assignment there, it will be harder to read but a little bit faster.

```
ar = [[param if i != j else diagonal
       for i in range(N)]
      for j in range(N)]
```

It's using a ternary expression, in simpler terms those look like `a if test else b`, where the value is set as `a` if `test` evaluates as `True`, and `b` if it evaluates as `False`. So this means that you just set the value as `param` when it's not a diagonal, and it's set as `diagonal` on the diagonals.

Answer (score 2):

You almost certainly want to preallocate the matrix at the correct, final size and *then* assign values other than the default.  Also look at [the array creation routines](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.array-creation.html) for predefined functions.

E.g. you could use `full` to fill with `param`, then use the loop for the diagonal.

Answer (score 2):

### Style review

From a style point of view, you are violating PEP8, and should name your variables somewhat differently. Maybe something like:

- `makeMatrix` into snakecase `make_matrix` or `fill_diagonal_matrix`. `make_matrix` is kind of anonymous and doesn't convey what the function does
- `ar` into `my_array`
- `st` into `_`, as you don't seem to use it
- `param` into `default_value`
- `N` into either `n` or `matrix_size`

And if using Python 2.x you should use `xrange(n)` as it doesn't generate the list, but uses a generator, which in turn will save you some memory and gain a little performance for large \$n\$'s.

### Code review

You don't need a list comprehension to initialise all the off-diagonals values, you simply multiply it. With new variable names, and a docstring your function could look like:

```
 def fill_diagonal_matrix(default_value, matrix_size):
    """Fill matrix with default_value, except a zeroing diagonal.

    That is all elements are equal to default_value, except down
    the diagonal which equals to: - default_value * (matrix_size - 1)
    """
    my_array = []
    for i in xrange(matrix_size):
        my_array.append([default_value] * matrix_size)
        my_array[i][i] = -default_value * (matrix_size - 1)
    return my_array
```

Answer (score -1):

Question is, do you really need an explicit matrix? For large \$N\$ it occupies a significant space while containing very little information. I'd go for a (wrapped) function instead:

```
    def make_special_matrix(N, param):
        def special_matrix(i, j):
            if i == j:
                return (N-1)*param
            return param
        return special_matrix
```

Comment: `N` is never going to be very large for me, and it does need to be in the form of a numpy array because I feed it into some Cython code that requires a numpy array